# How to set the sqlcmd.exe exit code?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, scripting

The script needs to test to see if a backup table already exists and stop if it does. This is to prevent overwriting a backup already created.

The following will stop further script execution (but not interpretation output). However, it does not set the exit code value. It needs to set the exit code value in order to support automation.

This needs to work even if the user is not sysadmin. Therefore, RAISEERROR() with a severity code > 18 and WITH LOG does not improve the situation.

The script needs to work in both sqlcmd.exe and SSMS on SQL Server as early as 2012.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BUDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_A')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'ERROR: Table BUDB.dbo.TABLE_A already exists.'
    RAISERROR('ERROR: Will not create existing backup table.', 18, -1);
    SET NOEXEC ON;
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BUDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_B')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'ERROR: Table BUDB.dbo.TABLE_B already exists.'
    RAISERROR('ERROR: Will not create existing backup table.', 18, -1);
    SET NOEXEC ON;
END
```

Comment: Use `RETURN someValue` maybe? Alternatively `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd rewrite the script to use the `XACT_ABORT_ON` and `TRY..CATCH` construct instead of the `SET NO EXEC ON`.

As per this recommendation by [Erland Sommarskog](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#essentialcommands)

This is my version of the script used for testing:

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @DbName sysname = DB_NAME()

    IF (@DbName LIKE 'm%')
    BEGIN 
       RAISERROR('ERROR: DbName starts with m', 16, -1); 
    END

    SELECT @@VERSION /* test if script continues */
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ;THROW /* Needed to rethrow the error*/
END CATCH
```

As for the **SQLCMD** there are two parameters:

- **-b** = terminate batch job if there is an error
- **-V** = error_severity_level

by default only errors with severity greater than 10, but you can override that with the *-V* parameter.

Here's a [link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16#:%7E:text=Error%20Reporting%20Options)

The sqlcmd execution could then look like this

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -d master -i "FullPath.sql" -b; $LASTEXITCODE
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the -b switch of sqlcmd ?
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16#command-line-options

Comment: Thank you. Using the `-b`  switch was the key to getting the exit code set. I selected Zikato's as the best answer because in addition to `-b`, it included information about `XACT_ABORT` as well. Even though the code there was not about testing the existence of a table.